# Nexus vs. Artifactory

Tags: artifactory, nexus

I was wondering what is the recommendation for a business that needs to store binaries for distribution as well as for dependencies to be used by our projects, with projects in different languages/technologies (.NET, Javascript/Java, C/C++, TAL).

Thank you, any info is appreciated!!

Answer (score 10):

Am using both right now.

Nexus will support more repo types with the free version than Artifactory

but

Artifactory will have more repos support in the paid tier

Nexus now support Conda natively (since a few weeks ago if memory serves)

Artifactory will be quite pricey, especially if you plan on having tests and staging instances to test out your config and/or custom plugins as you will have to shell for at least a Pro instance (3K+USD).  Nexus will allow you to test most of these with the free version.

JFrog has exemplary support but a bit pushy with their sales.  They will have help around though to get you started should you need it.

I have not tried Nexus support or sales force so I cant comment (the free version was plenty enough for our needs).

I found the plugin framework to be more usable with Artifactory though it felt a bit limited.  Nexus seems more powerfull but it can be difficult to upgrade/remove plugins from a working instance.  On that front I much preferred Artifactory.

Overall we did go with Artifactory, personally I find them to be pretty much equivalent.  It will depend a bit on the actual technology you need supported (pypi, nuget, maven etc).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, it gives me better insight!!

Answer (score 9):

I have used both in enterprise settings a fair bit, but I had never really thought this through until reading the question.  Artifactory seems much more complete/impressive to me, but I have used it more recently than Neuxs, so I was worried that I might be biased.

I just spent ~30 minutes reading online.  Virtually every comparison or article is either totally biased (literally JFROG or Sonatype supported), or is just lacking in detail.

I eventually did find this though, which is fairly in line with my initial thoughts:  https://www.praqma.com/stories/artifactory-nexus-proget/:

- Artifactory supports far more repository types.
- Atifactory has a far better REST API (and has often been ahead on feature development, though it seems like Nexus does catch up over time).
- Nexus is a little more extensible.
- Artifactory costs significantly more.

So... both are good.  If you aren't amazingly cost conscious and want the best overall tool, probably choose artifactory.  If you have specific needs and Nexus covers your required repository types, it might be worth using it to save some money as it is a solid product in the end.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, and for taking the time to find a good article!! The link you posted was full of good information :)

Answer (score 3):

To add more info to John's answer above: the author of that comparison article updated it at https://www.eficode.com/blog/artifactory-nexus-proget

From my opinion, I left jFrog and went with Nexus because Nexus free version has all my needs (repo type: Maven, yum, pypi and Docker; feature: proxy repo, private repo, group repo; authentication: LDAP/Active directory).
Since I am neither using CI/CI feature nor opening my repo to the internet, I couldn't (and shouldn't) give any comments on that point.